# Python: Find time difference between consecutive lines in a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with contents like the following:

```
12:10:41.016 U
12:11:10.517 D
12:11:11.516 D
12:12:01.233 U
```

I want a output like this:

```
29 D-U
1 D-D
80 U-D
```

,which means (i+1)-the line - i-th line -> Time difference in seconds + Tags(U/D).

I'm approaching like

```
for num, line in enumerate(open("foo.txt")):
```

but getting confused; how do I use the 'num' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying won't work because you don't have an array of lines to index while you are iterating.  You only have the current line.  But to calculate the time difference, you need access to both the current line and the previous line.

Instead I would iterate in pairs of lines, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import tee, izip
from functools import partial

def pairwise(iterable):
    """Iterate in pairs

    >>> list(pairwise([0, 1, 2, 3]))
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def parse_time(time_str, time_format='%H:%M:%S.%f'):
    return datetime.strptime(time_str, time_format)

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for (time0, flag0), (time1, flag1) in pairwise(line.split() for line in f):
        delta = parse_time(time1) - parse_time(time0)
        print '{} {}-{}'.format(delta.total_seconds(), flag1, flag0)
```

This gives the time difference in float, you can always round/truncate it if you want.  Note I don't see how you get 80 seconds for the last line in your example, shouldn't it be 50 seconds?